Error en pygame Fatal Python error: pygame_parachute
Tengo el siguiente código:
Es el código más básico para un programa de pygame en python.
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 75)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()

Y al ejecutar muestra el siguiente error:
pygame-ce 2.4.1 (SDL 2.28.5, Python 3.11.3)
Fatal Python error: pygame_parachute: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00001f88 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\github\prueba.py", line 2 in <module>

Extension modules: pygame.base, pygame.constants, pygame.rect, pygame.rwobject, pygame.surflock, pygame.bufferproxy, pygame.math, pygame.surface, pygame.window, pygame.display, pygame.draw, pygame.joystick, pygame.event, pygame.imageext, pygame.image, pygame.key, pygame.mouse, pygame.time, pygame.mask, pygame.pixelcopy, pygame.transform, pygame.font, pygame.mixer_music, pygame.mixer, pygame.scrap, pygame.system, pygame._freetype (total: 27)

Nunca había visto esto.
Qué significa todo eso...???
Gracias.

Tu código parece correcto, y el mensaje me da la impresión de que se trata de un error interno en Pygame. Quizá el asunto se ha mencionado en los issues de pygame en github. Revisaste por ahí? Una hipotesis que podemos barajar es que haya alguna incompatibilidad entre pygame y tu software (por ejemplo, la versión de python no es compatibñe con la de pygame)

El error es una violación de acceso/segmento, generalmente ocurre cuando un proceso intenta acceder a memoria que no le pertenece, que no está asignada a el por el SO. Pygame es una extensión escrita mayormente en C y como cualquier y el código en C, por la naturaleza del lenguaje, es bastante susceptible de este tipo de errores y hay mil causas (acceso a punteros colgantes o no inicializados, cadenas sin terminación, indizar fuera de los limites de un array, mal uso de los métodos para reservar/liberar memoria dinámica, .... )

El error parece producirse tempranamente, en la inicialización de Pygame, podrían ser mil cosas, desde algún bug en el código de C de Pygame, problemas al reservar/comprobar memoria durante la incialización, podría venir de SDL o incluso del intérprete de Python... He intentado reproducir el error en Linux en un VENV limpio, con Python 3.11.8 y las mismas versiones de SDL y pygame-ce para ver si había suerte y podía reproducirlo para ver si faulthandler, GDB o  valgrind  me decían algo, pero no, el código funciona sin problemas.... En Python 3.12 tampoco hay problemas.

En github hay algunas issues relacionadas pero no muy recientes y parecen casos más específicos (aunque no lo he revisado a fondo). Sería bueno ver si alguien en Windows puede reproducirlo por sis se debe al algo especifico del build de pg-ce en PyPi para este SO o sus versiones de SDL, etc Podrías intentar actualizar Python y también compilar pygame-ce desde las fuentes directamente.

@FJSevilla Probé en Windows 11, con la versión de Python 3.10.8 y pygame actualizado, y no ocurre el error mencionado.
